# Change dataType of spark dataframe column in SparkR

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

I have a spark dataframe.

```
root
 |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col3: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col4: string (nullable = true)
 |-- date1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col5: string (nullable = true)
 |-- date2: string (nullable = true)
```

I just want to convert the date2 column to date. I used the below code to do that

```
to_date(myDF$date2)
```

But the dataframe remains the same. No change in date2 datatype.

How can I change the column date2 to date dataType?

Comment: The convention in R is that you need to make an assignment in order to make a transformation "stick". This question does not actually have sufficient information to test any code.

Comment: That does solve my problem ```myDF$date2 <- to_date(myDF$date2)```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
myDF <- withColumn(myDF, "date2", cast(myDF$date2, "date"))
```

See these pages in the SparkR documentation for the latest version (2.0.1 at the time of writing this):

- [SparkR: cast](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/api/R/cast.html)
- [SparkR: withColumn](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/api/R/withColumn.html)

The cast will not change the existing dataframe, so you need to create a new dataframe or replace the existing dataframe with the newly casted column replacing the old column of the same name.